# How do upgrade OpenManage from 6.5 to 7 in CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, dell, dell-openmanage

How do I upgrade OpenManage? When I download the rpm there are no scripts include in the tar file, and the Dell repo doesn't seem to have OpenManage 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download OpenManage (Probably better off going via Dell's website to get the latest, but for the lazy):

```
wget ftp://ftp.dell.com/FOLDER00298767M/1/OM-MgmtStat-Dell-Web-LX-7.0.0-4614_A00.tar.gz
#The following a tar bomb (Go Dell, might want to make a directory first) 
tar zxf OM-MgmtStat-Dell-Web-LX-7.0.0-4614_A00.tar.gz
```

Remove the old version:

```
sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep srvadmin)
sudo yum erase libsmbios.x86_64
```

Install the new RPMs (After getting the newest version of lubsmbios):

```
[kbrandt@ny-lb05: ~/linux/rac/RHEL6/x86_64] sudo rpm -i *.rpm
```

Enable at boot:

```
[kbrandt@ny-lb05: /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin] sudo ./srvadmin-services.sh enable
instsvcdrv      0:on    1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:on
dataeng         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Start it up:

```
[kbrandt@ny-lb05: /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin] sudo ./srvadmin-services.sh start
Starting Systems Management Device Drivers:
Starting dell_rbu:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting ipmi driver: Already started                      [  OK  ]
Starting Systems Management Data Engine:
Starting dsm_sa_datamgrd:                                  [  OK  ]
Starting dsm_sa_eventmgrd:                                 [  OK  ]
Starting dsm_sa_snmpd:                                     [  OK  ]
```